# Receive Call with TAPI3 in delphi

Tags: delphi, netapi32

When I program tapi3 in delphi 7 using the code below, I can make a
outgoing call, but I can't catch any events. Has anybody face the same
problem ?

```
unit Unit10;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls,
Forms,
  Dialogs, TAPI3Lib_TLB, StdCtrls, ActiveX, ComObj, OleServer;
{
type
  TTapiEventsSink = class( TObject, IConnectionPointContainer, I)
    procedure TAPI1Event(ASender: TObject; TapiEvent: TOleEnum;
      const pEvent: IDispatch);
  end;
}
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button3: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button4: TButton;
    TAPI1: TTAPI;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TAPI1Event(ASender: TObject; TapiEvent: TOleEnum;
      const pEvent: IDispatch);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    tapi3 : ITTAPI;
    addr : ITAddress;
    media : ITMediaSupport;
    addrs : IEnumAddress;
    term : ITTerminal;
    terminalSupport : ITTerminalSupport;
    basicall :ITBasicCallControl;
    dir : TOleEnum;

    streamControl : ITStreamControl;
    enumStream : IEnumStream;
    stream : ITStream;
    mediatype : Integer;
    direct : TERMINAL_DIRECTION;
    lAddressType : Integer;
    bHold : Boolean;

    event : ITCallNotificationEvent;
    tapievent : ITTAPIEventNotification;
    unknown : IUnknown;

  end;

const TAPI3_CALL_EVENTS =
        TE_CALLMEDIA OR
        TE_CALLNOTIFICATION OR
        TE_CALLSTATE;
const
  TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO = $8;
  TAPIMEDIATYPE_VEDIO = $8000;
  TAPIMEDIATYPE_DATEMODEM = $10;
  TAPIMEDIATYPE_G3FAX = $20;
  LINEADDRESSTYPE_PHONENUMBER = $00000001;
  EVENT_FILTER =
    TE_TAPIOBJECT OR
    TE_ADDRESS OR
    TE_CALLNOTIFICATION OR
    TE_CALLSTATE OR
    TE_CALLMEDIA OR
    TE_CALLHUB OR
    TE_CALLINFOCHANGE OR
    TE_PRIVATE OR
    TE_REQUEST OR
    TE_AGENT OR
    TE_AGENTSESSION OR
    TE_QOSEVENT OR
    TE_AGENTHANDLER OR
    TE_ACDGROUP OR
    TE_QUEUE OR
    TE_DIGITEVENT OR
    TE_GENERATEEVENT;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  lwCeltFetched : Cardinal;
  cookievar : Integer;
begin
  bHold := false;

  tapi1.Initialize;
  tapi1.Connect;

  { Select an address }
  // list address
  addrs := tapi1.DefaultInterface.EnumerateAddresses;
  //addrs := tapi3.EnumerateAddresses;
  while ( S_OK = addrs.Next(1,addr,lwCeltFetched) ) do
  begin
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(addr.AddressName);
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

    basicall.Disconnect(DC_NORMAL);

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lwCeltFetched : Cardinal;
  iRes : Integer;
  i : Integer;
  hr : Integer;

begin

  { Select an address }
  addrs.Reset;
  while ( S_OK = addrs.Next(1,addr,lwCeltFetched) ) do
    begin
      hr := addr.QueryInterface(IID_ITMediaSupport,media);
      if ( true = media.QueryMediaType(TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO) ) then
        break;
    end;


  tapi1.EventFilter := EVENT_FILTER;

tapi1.RegisterCallNotifications(addr,true,false,TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO,1);


end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  phonenum : array [0..30] of char;
begin
    lAddressType := LINEADDRESSTYPE_PHONENUMBER;
    StrPCopy( phonenum, Edit1.Text );
    basicall :=
addr.CreateCall(phonenum,lAddressType,TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO);
    basicall.Connect(false);


end;

procedure TForm1.TAPI1Event(ASender: TObject; TapiEvent: TOleEnum;
  const pEvent: IDispatch);
var
  callinfo : ITCallInfo;
  event : ITCallNotificationEvent;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('hi');
  Memo1.Refresh;
  case TapiEvent of
  TE_CALLNOTIFICATION :
    begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('call notification');
    end;
  end;

end;
```

I need to get Caller ID when someone call me through the modem.

Thanks .

Comment: Have you considered the freeware [AsynchPro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/) that makes all of this much simpler? It's an open-sourced formerly commercial product from TurboPower that makes all of this stuff as easy as dropping a component on a form and creating event handlers through the Object Inspector.

Comment: [Tapi events and Borland Delphi](http://www.44342.com/win32-f42-t447-p1.htm)